# File APIs Javascript FileReader onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, fileapi

I am using File APIs with Javascript.

 I need to wait for the completation of onload method, how can I do it?

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
    contents = reader.result;
    var addAttchCallBack = loadRequestExecutor();
    addAttchCallBack.done(function (data) {
        alert("ok");   
    })
};
alert("Ko");
```

I see always before "Ko"
N.B: the function loadRequestExecutor() correctly returns a promise obj.
Thanks,Nk

Comment: return addAttachCallBack.then(function(data){ alert("ok");return data;})` you need to return thh promise. Also assuming you already know how asynchronous coding works in JS - did you read the 'coverting a callback api to promises' question yet?

Comment: The problem is that the onLoad is asynch.
I tried 
$.when(reader.onload = function (e) {
            contents = reader.result;
            return loadRequestExecutor();
        }).done(function (a) {
              alert("ok");
        });
        alert("KO");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises

Answer (score 1):

You really need to study up on Async behavior *and* callbacks, then take on understanding `promises`, as your examples are an odd combination of callbacks and promises, but, to try and explain what is going on in basic terms:

### Example 1:

You always seeing `KO` first, because the first example does this:

1. Assign a function to a property that will be called back later
2. Show a KO alert
3. At some time later the file loads, starts the executor, which on complete (if it ever does) alerts OK

so, basically your `onload` function will only get called after the file loads (asynchronously), so the `alert` on the next line gets executed immediately.

### Example 2:

You second example, in a comment, is this:

```
$.when(reader.onload = function (e) {
    contents = reader.result;
    return loadRequestExecutor();
}).done(function (a) {
    alert("ok");
});
alert("KO");
```

Which translates to:

1. Assign a function to a property that will be called back later
2. Pass that same function to `when` but do not execute it!!!
3. Show a KO alert
4. At some time later when the file loads, return the loadRequestExecutor() to the filereader!!!

The end result is *not* returning the promise to the wait, which is what you probably meant, so it will never work as expected.

**Suggestion:**

I do not know the plugins that well, but you appear to need to record a promise relating to the load request executor, if that is what you want to wait for.

```
// Create the loadRequestExecutor and record the promise
var addAttchCallBack = loadRequestExecutor();

// Setup the onload callback  
reader.onload = function (e) {
    contents = reader.result;
    alert("ok - file load is done");   
};

// Listen for the loadRequestExecutor to complete
addAttchCallBack.done(function (data) {
    alert("Ko - loadRequestExecutor is done");
})

alert("I am just an alert that will happen first, as everything above is asynchronous!");
```

*Your overall aim is not clear from the question, so this answer mainly focuses on exampling why your two attempts do not work as you expected.*